# Transitive gradle depencies not resolved from aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-module

I have made a custom module and included tensorflow-lite dependency in it with 'api' configuration. I build its aar. Now I create a new project and put the aar in libs folder. But I can access only the classes I created and not the tensorflow api. How can I use the transitive dependencies too without including them again?

I have replaced 'implementation' with 'api' as I read that in a blog (https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa).

build.gradle(Module:mylib)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions{
        noCompress "tflite"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    api 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-gpu-experimental'
}
```

build.gradle(Module:two in a new project):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
                cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-frtti", "-fexceptions"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://google.bintray.com/tensorflow' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    api project(':openCVLibrary341')
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Generally **aar files** doesn't contain third party dependencies. Try including your whole project *(your openCVLibrary341 library here)* as module and then use **api** instead of **implementation** in your app module.

Comment: my problem is that I cannot use the tensorflow-lite dependency which I have added in mylib.aar in my module two. Transitive dependencies are not working.

Comment: Yes that's what i mentioned earlier, you'll need to create fat-aar or else import your library as module in your project. *(transitive won't work in such case, creating fat-aar will cause issue in future.)*